# can't connect to google talk using jabber.el

Tags: emacs, google-talk, jabber

I'm trying to set up my Google talk on jabber.el to chat from Emacs. My Emacs version is 24.2.1 and jabber.el version is 0.8.0 (at least, this is what jabber-info tells me). My configuration is:

```
        JID: yotama9@gmail.com
        [ ] Disabled
        [ ] Password: 
        [X] Network server: talk.google.com
        [ ] Port: 5222
        [X] Connection type: Value Menu Legacy SSL/TLS
```

and the message I get (after `C-x C-j C-x`) is:

```
Opening TLS connection to `talk.google.com'...
Opening TLS connection with `gnutls-cli --insecure -p 5223 talk.google.com'...failed
Opening TLS connection with `gnutls-cli --insecure -p 5223 talk.google.com --protocols ssl3'...failed
Opening TLS connection with `openssl s_client -connect talk.google.com:5223 -no_ssl2 -ign_eof'...failed
Opening TLS connection to `talk.google.com'...failed
Jabber connection failed
yotama9@gmail.com/nil: connection lost: `nil'
```

I tried searching for this problem and couldn't find any. I'm using this behind organization firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ ] Password:
```

Don't you need your password for yotama9@gmail.com put in for this to connect?  According to [google](http://support.google.com/talk/answer/27930?hl=en):

> In order to connect to Google Talk and start sending IMs, you'll need
>   to enable TCP connections to talk.google.com on port 5222, or on port
>   443.

Make sure to use port 5222 or 443 not 5223

Comment: If I give the password Emacs just hang without connecting. Also, [here](http://emacs-jabber.sourceforge.net/manual-0.8.0/Account-settings.html#Account-settings) they tell me I don't need to do so.

Comment: I read that it says "You can set the password of the account, so you don't have to enter it when you connect. Note that it will be stored unencrypted in your customization file. "  This means you either have to set it in the configuration, or enter it when you connect.  Also, correct what port you are using, per my answer.

Comment: @Yotam - Glad to be of service.